# .net manifest query string

Tags: .net, manifest

How can I parse the query string (GET / POST parameters) sent to an application's manifest in .NET ?
From one application, I am calling `MyApp.application` which needs to install my .NET application (if not installed) and in any case it should call the application which should parse the GET parameters.

Later edit:
I have a .NET application which should be installed via ClickOnce. It's already published on a web server. The execution of the application is done by calling the `MyApp.application` file from an external application (written in PHP). This normally checks for updates and installs the application if required, then it calls the application so this is the file that will always be called from the external app.
The external app sends parameters via a GET query to this file which should be processed in the .NET app (the parameters include credentials information because this the easiest way I can see to implement automatic login).
If the GET parameters are sent to `MyApp.application`, how can I process them in `MyApp.cs` every time it's launched?

Comment: Please add a bit more context. It's not clear (to me at least) what is making the HTTP request, what's receiving it, or what you want the effect to be. What kind of installation are you talking about?

Comment: Hopefully this is more clear. If not, I will draw a small diagram :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that query string options are enabled (project properties=>publish=>options=>manifests=>allow url parameters...);

Then - to allow parity between standalone and web, I use something like below (the important bit is `ActivationArguments.ActivationData`; you'll need a reference to `System.Deployment.dll` too).

You could also look at `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri`, which MSDN has a good example for [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.activationuri.aspx).

---

```
    public static string[] GetStartupArguments() {
        List<string> allOptions = new List<string>();
        try // command line
        {
            string[] options = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
            if (options != null) { // strip the first (the exe name)
                int length = options.Length;
                for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
                    allOptions.Add(options[i]);
            }
        } catch { } // lazy swallow
        try // query string
        {
            if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) {
                string[] options = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;
                if (options != null && options.Length > 0) {
                    foreach (string queryItem in new Uri(options[0]).Query.TrimStart('?').Split('&')) {
                        allOptions.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(queryItem));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch { } // lazy swallow

        return allOptions.ToArray();
    }
```